# timezone from dates squence POSIXct lost when coercing to data.frame in R

Tags: r, timezone, posixct

I would like to keep the CET, CEST part of the data sequence generated below.

```
seq(as.POSIXct("2018-10-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-10-02"), "hour")
myvector <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-10-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-10-02"), "hour")
myvector
mydf <- as.data.frame(myvector)
```

Which in console looks like:

```
> head(seq(...))

[1] "2018-10-01 00:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 01:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 02:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 03:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 04:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 05:00:00 CEST"

> head(myvector)

[1] "2018-10-01 00:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 01:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 02:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 03:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 04:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 05:00:00 CEST"

> head(mydf)
             myvector
1 2018-10-01 00:00:00
2 2018-10-01 01:00:00
3 2018-10-01 02:00:00
4 2018-10-01 03:00:00
5 2018-10-01 04:00:00
6 2018-10-01 05:00:00
>
```

When I coerce it to data.frame it get lost. I do not know how to keep it, I have tried things like:

`attr(mydf$myvector, "tzone") <- attr(myvector, "tzone")` but `tzone` is not really an attribute so it does not work.

What is `CEST/CET` within the `POSIXct`? How Can I keep it when coercing to df?

Thanks

Comment: It's not lost - `head(mydf$myvector)`

Comment: Ups, true. Thanks! 

How could I access to that part of the POSIXct? (Apart from coercing to string and extract the corresponding part) 

I have tried with the attr() and "tz" "tzone" "timezone" but did not get it to work. 

Thanks

Comment: With `attributes(mydf$myvector)`

I just got:

`$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

$tzone
[1] ""
`

I would like wether to append a new column to the dataframe or keeip it vissible under the same column.

Comment: Something like this `mydf$timezone <- tz(mydf$myvector)`? (i.e. by having a separate column to display timezone)

Comment: Hi @Prem , thanks your your answer.

I can see that when with `head(mydf$myvector)` the good values are printed (e.g. `"2018-04-01 00:00:00 CEST"`.

However, when I try to access the tz attribute it is empty:

`attributes(mydf$myvector) ` gives `$class [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
$tzone [1] ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `as.POSIXlt` on `POSIXct` column before fetching timezone from it

```
#Extract timezone from POSIXct column of a dataframe
mydf$timezone <- attr(as.POSIXlt(mydf$myvector), "tzone")[1]

head(mydf)
#             myvector      timezone
#1 2018-10-01 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin
#2 2018-10-01 01:00:00 Europe/Berlin
#3 2018-10-01 02:00:00 Europe/Berlin
#4 2018-10-01 03:00:00 Europe/Berlin
#5 2018-10-01 04:00:00 Europe/Berlin
#6 2018-10-01 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin
```

**Sample data:**

```
myvector <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-10-01"), as.POSIXct("2018-10-02"), "hour")
head(myvector)
#[1] "2018-10-01 00:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 01:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 02:00:00 CEST"
#[4] "2018-10-01 03:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 04:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 05:00:00 CEST"

mydf <- as.data.frame(myvector)
head(mydf$myvector)
#[1] "2018-10-01 00:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 01:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 02:00:00 CEST"
#[4] "2018-10-01 03:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 04:00:00 CEST" "2018-10-01 05:00:00 CEST"
```

**Alternate approach:** If you really care about `CET` or `CEST` output only

```
mydf$timezone <- gsub("^.*\\s", "", format(mydf$myvector, usetz = TRUE))

head(mydf)
#             myvector timezone
#1 2018-10-01 00:00:00     CEST
#2 2018-10-01 01:00:00     CEST
#3 2018-10-01 02:00:00     CEST
#4 2018-10-01 03:00:00     CEST
#5 2018-10-01 04:00:00     CEST
#6 2018-10-01 05:00:00     CEST
```

Comment: Hi Prem, thanks again.

Your solution works if in the period selected for the sequence there is not a daylight savings time modification. 

In Europe, March 25th, 2018 there was a time change, and the tzone moved from CET (Centro European Time) to (Center Summer European Time).

Any idea on how to tackle this issue?

`myvector <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-03-25"), as.POSIXct("2018-03-26"), "hour")
head(myvector)
mydf <- as.data.frame(myvector)
head(mydf$myvector)
mydf$timezone <- attr(as.POSIXlt(mydf$myvector), "tzone")
head(mydf)`

Comment: Do you want `CET` or `CEST` only? How about `Europe/Berlin`? Otherwise the only possibility seems to be using substring of character date (see the updated answer).

Comment: Yeah I would like to have the CET/CEST column in the data set.

Your solution seems to work pefectly. Could you please explain the `^.*\\s` expression?

Does it means "Everything before the second space (included)?

Comment: Glad that it helped! `^.*\\s` means everything (`.*`) from start (`^`) till the last occurrence of space (`\\s`) (for more info refer [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)).